# DocuSign Email Notifications - How to remove email address and name from the body of the email

Tags: html, email, docusignapi

DocuSign notifications are being sent out with the DocuSign account owners name and email within the body of the email. Worked with DocuSign support and determined modification needs to be made to the email resource file (there is also a signing resource file) and this is not something DocuSign support can help with.

I am trying to remove/hide the Name and Email Address from the body of the email. I have attached a screenshot example.

Which line in the resource file (I can attach both email and signing resource files here if necessary) would need to be modified? Would it also be multiple lines that need to be modified?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We recommend that any changes done to the resource file should be performed by an HTML knowledgeable person, because this file contains settings for the entire account.

If you want to make the changes yourself you can look up the appropiate section by searching for the text "your documents have been completed".

We hope this helps

Adrian
DocuSign Support